Change color of inline svg inside <img> tag
I was wondering if it's possible to change the color of a SVG image/icon/logo in an inline html  <img> tag, using style="..."
Here's part of my code, it's a button and I want the logo (only the SVG) to be the color indicated
<a href="#" class="nav-link btn btn-outline-secondary d-flex border-0 w-100" style="color:#39384A;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Discord">
  <img class="m-auto" src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/353655/discord-icon.svg" style="color:#39384A;">
</a>

As you can see, the color doesn't change, it remains the color of the SVG file.
I need it to be inline since I don't have access to the CSS sheet to change the CSS of certain tags and classes (not my website, customization is limited)
thanks!

Hey, you can not apply colors directly but what you can do is to play around with css filter property to change the svg image using inline style. here is a very useful link that can generate css for you.
https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp

You cannot change the color of an external SVG file directly through the style attribute of an <img> tag.
However, you can achieve this by embedding the SVG directly in the HTML and applying the desired color via CSS.
Here's how you might do so:

Download the SVG file.
Open the SVG file and copy its content.
Paste the SVG content directly into your HTML.
Apply the color change using CSS.

Here's your modified code with the SVG content inline and styled:
<a href="#" class="nav-link btn btn-outline-secondary d-flex border-0 w-100" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Discord">
  <svg width="800px" height="800px" viewBox="0 -28.5 256 256" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
    <g>
      <path d="M216.856339,16.5966031 C200.285002,8.84328665 182.566144,3.2084988 164.041564,0 C161.766523,4.11318106 159.108624,9.64549908 157.276099,14.0464379 C137.583995,11.0849896 118.072967,11.0849896 98.7430163,14.0464379 C96.9108417,9.64549908 94.1925838,4.11318106 91.8971895,0 C73.3526068,3.2084988 55.6133949,8.86399117 39.0420583,16.6376612 C5.61752293,67.146514 -3.4433191,116.400813 1.08711069,164.955721 C23.2560196,181.510915 44.7403634,191.567697 65.8621325,198.148576 C71.0772151,190.971126 75.7283628,183.341335 79.7352139,175.300261 C72.104019,172.400575 64.7949724,168.822202 57.8887866,164.667963 C59.7209612,163.310589 61.5131304,161.891452 63.2445898,160.431257 C105.36741,180.133187 151.134928,180.133187 192.754523,160.431257 C194.506336,161.891452 196.298154,163.310589 198.110326,164.667963 C191.183787,168.842556 183.854737,172.420929 176.223542,175.320965 C180.230393,183.341335 184.861538,190.991831 190.096624,198.16893 C211.238746,191.588051 232.743023,181.531619 254.911949,164.955721 C260.227747,108.668201 245.831087,59.8662432 216.856339,16.5966031 Z M85.4738752,135.09489 C72.8290281,135.09489 62.4592217,123.290155 62.4592217,108.914901 C62.4592217,94.5396472 72.607595,82.7145587 85.4738752,82.7145587 C98.3405064,82.7145587 108.709962,94.5189427 108.488529,108.914901 C108.508531,123.290155 98.3405064,135.09489 85.4738752,135.09489 Z M170.525237,135.09489 C157.88039,135.09489 147.510584,123.290155 147.510584,108.914901 C147.510584,94.5396472 157.658606,82.7145587 170.525237,82.7145587 C183.391518,82.7145587 193.761324,94.5189427 193.539891,108.914901 C193.539891,123.290155 183.391518,135.09489 170.525237,135.09489 Z" fill="#39384A" fill-rule="nonzero">
      </path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</a>

Note the style="fill:#39384A;" which will change the SVG to the specified color.
